# How to investigate "inflateInit: out of memory" in git cherry-pick?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

Background issue is that at $dayjob I've an automated process performing cherrypicks on a server (basically waits to be modified of branches of interest, cherrypicks them on various targets, and pushes those new branches out), on a pretty large repository (a few GBs, though the cherrypicks tend to be only a few commits at a time).

Usually this works fine, but from time to time a cherrypick will fail with a status 128 (which apparently means a `die()` call), and the only output of

> inflateInit: out of memory (no message)

- I've seen no commonality between the failing cherry-picks, they touch different files, have a different number of commits, different authors, ...
- `fsck` on the repository (on the server) doesn't show anything suspicious
- since there is no other output and `cherry-pick` has no `verbose` flag, there is no information coming from git
- the memory load of the server is usually low (right now it's at 2.6GiB / 8GiB), it has plenty of headroom, and even with a serious repack (`-AbFd --window=500`) everything fits within physical memory with room to spare
- there is no CPU or memory load warning on the monitoring, though that is unlikely as the cherry-pick process finishes very quickly (<2s) and the monitoring doesn't poll anywhere near that fast

I'm not quite sure how to try and investigate the issue to resolve it, whether it's a configuration error (missing configuration), a usage problem, ...

Comment: Does it fail consistently ? e.g : when you meet a failure, does running the exact same `cherry-pick` command a second time trigger the same error ?

Comment: Good question, I'll have to add something to try this out (or try it out on the server after notifying a failure): currently when it fails it just bails and leaves an operator do it by hand. Said operator would be doing it on their own machine which doesn't behave the same.

Comment: Yes, the "process" I mention is automated, I'll edit the post to make that clearer.

Comment: Ok, as you said : you would have to log stuff to better understand what's failing. e.g : the cherry-pick command that is run, possibly a stack trace of your script/process when it fails ...

Comment: There's realy nothing I can log here: the full output of the cherrypick command is what I quoted above (and the inputs and outputs are logged, I didn't put them there because they're just commit hashes being fed to cherrypick). The script itself doesn't fail, it just sees that the cherrypick failed and reports that information for manual processing (this is mostly intended for conflicts which need to be resolved manually).

Comment: You can insert `export GIT_TRACE=2` in your automation to have Git dump trace information to stderr.

Comment: Ok, I meant : if it sees a failure, your script can do something like `echo \`date\`" $cmd" >> /tmp/myscript.log` (or an equivalent in your script's language) when it sees that `$cmd` exited with a non zero code. If it runs stuff in a loop, perhaps also add the index of the loop, or info like the output of `free -h` right after the failure ...

Comment: Your machine is probably literally running out of memory. How much RAM does it have, and how much swap space for doing paging?

Comment: @j6t interesting suggestion, I'll try that out!

Comment: @LeGEC the output is shoved into a full log, I have the exact moment at which the errors happen, hence my note that the cherry-pick runs for less than 2s way below any monitoring threshold.

Comment: @torek that's in the post. The server has 8GB physical but normally sits at 2.6GB used. Even doing a `repack -AdFb` with a large window which is an expensive operation both CPU and memory-wise it does not OOM. It didn't historically have swap though after the last error I added 8GB swap with a very low priority (`vm.swappiness=10`) to use as a rough memory-tracking tool.

Comment: Oh, right, I missed the one bullet point entirely. Hm, 5 GB should usually be enough. Depends on how big your big repo is, though. I used to build something that would occasionally need about 20 GB of RAM at a time (rather painful on a 16 GB machine, lots of paging, not so bad on 64+ GB machines), but that wasn't because of huge Git repos.